# Hello World Program With 3 Arguments, Keeps throwing me errors I don't understand

Tags: java

I am making a simple hello world program that prints "Hello World" and prints 3 arguments that I specify. All my code seems to be right, but I cannot understand the errors.

```js
public class Test 
{
    public static void Main(String[] args){
        string name = {"khem", "Parsad", "Bajgai"};
                
        
        {
        if (args.length > 0) 
            name = args[0];
        if (args.length > 1)
            name = args[2]
        if (args.length > 2)
            name = args[3];
            
        }
        System.out.println("Hello, " + name + "!");
    }
}
```

I understand the line and character count of where the error is happening, but it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: The code you supplied is Java not JavaScript

Comment: Whoops. My apologies for the wrong tag.

However now everything seems to work fine after testing it with the edits you all suggested. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Based on some comments on a now-deleted answer, it is unclear what language this is actually supposed to be in; as written, it could not possibly compile and run as a Java program. A "CS1041: Identifier expected" error mentioned by OP suggests it may be C#. OP needs to confirm the source language.

Comment: Yeah I tried posting it earlier but answer had been deleted. For sure the program language is Java, however the ide I was using to execute the code was set to run it as C# code by default, and after switching it to Java, and re-compiling the code, I had no errors thrown back at me.

I did change the punctuation and capitalization errors and that's what fixed it all.

@David In the future I'd try being more patient with people rather than attack them when they have had less than a week programming experience. It makes me not wanna use the site if I will be getting answers like that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a ; is missing after name = args[2]

So i have to look as

```
 name = args[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

`public static void Main(String[] args)` should be `public static void main(String[] args)`

Also see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here...

```
string name = "khem"; "Parsad"; "Bajgai";
```

change that to...

```
String name = "";
```

By the way, you got the programming language tagged wrong...it's JAVA, not javascript

Answer (score 0):

use an array instead of using string

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void Main(String[] args){
        string name = ["khem", "Parsad", "Bajgai"];



        for(int i = 0; i< name.length; i++){
          System.println("Hello, " + name[i] + "!");
        }
    }
}
```